# CSS recalculate nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a image gallery with a 2 column layout. The image gallery can contain 1 column full width images between the 2 column images.

See my Codepen Example:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img class="large" src="http://nosrc.io/400x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img class="large" src="http://nosrc.io/400x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
    <img src="http://nosrc.io/200x200">
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdgBOb

Why does `:nth-child` select the wrong gallery items after the second full width image? Normally all left column images should have `margin-left: 0;` and all right column images should have `margin-left: 2%;`.

P.S. I can not use JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think `nth-child` is doing what you think it's doing. It's not the nth-child relative to the `.large` element; it's relative to **all** the `img` children of `.gallery`. If you use the style inspector and examine the styles being applied to each `img`, you should be able to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To really get this working properly (assuming your image sizes may be dynamic) you'll need to use [`.large:nth-of-type(...) ~ img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) and it will get pretty complicated (not to mention it may not work on some older browsers). An easier solution would just be to use 1% margin on all images: http://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/MwNBMK.

Comment: Sometimes, it's so easy ;-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

check it out. That says:

```
.gallery img:nth-child(2n+1) {
        margin-left: 0;
}
```

and:

```
.gallery img.large ~ img:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

the `(2n+1)` changes in what position uses the attribute

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't *this* suffice? I know but that theres unnecessary right margin in each line of images, but..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdeyzP

I also took the liberty of refactoring that weird float clearing.

```
.gallery {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Insetad of the bloaty:

```
.gallery::before,
.gallery::after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
}

.gallery::after {
        clear: both;
}
`
```

Since `overflow: hidden` is a [pretty good clearfix](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/) on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `nth-child` is doing what you think it's doing. It's not the nth-child relative to the `.large` element; it's relative to all the `img` children of `.gallery`. If you use the style inspector and examine the styles being applied to each img, you should be able to see what I mean.

You could try a rule like this:

```
.gallery img {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.gallery img.large {
  width: 98%;
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqQLYx.